# Cannot find module formidable - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm starting to develop with node.j,I meet an issue regarding the using of the module 'formidable'.

I have this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'formidable'

Here is the module list installed using 'npm ls installed' :

```
├─┬ express@2.5.9 
│ ├── connect@1.8.7 
│ ├── mime@1.2.4 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ └── qs@0.4.2 
├── formidable@1.0.9 
├─┬ node-inspector@0.1.10 
│ ├── paperboy@0.0.3 
│ └─┬ socket.io@0.8.7 
│   ├── policyfile@0.0.4 
│   ├── redis@0.6.7 
│   └─┬ socket.io-client@0.8.7 
│     ├── uglify-js@1.0.6 
│     ├── websocket-client@1.0.0 
│     └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2 
├─┬ npm@1.1.21 
│ ├── abbrev@1.0.3 
│ ├── archy@0.0.2 
│ ├── block-stream@0.0.5 
│ ├── chownr@0.0.1 
│ ├── fstream@0.1.18 
│ ├─┬ fstream-npm@0.0.6 
│ │ └── fstream-ignore@0.0.5 
│ ├── graceful-fs@1.1.8 
│ ├── inherits@1.0.0 
│ ├── ini@1.0.2 
│ ├── lru-cache@1.0.5 
│ ├── minimatch@0.2.2 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ ├─┬ node-gyp@0.4.1 
│ │ ├── ansi@0.0.4 
│ │ └── glob@3.1.9 
│ ├── node-uuid@1.3.3 
│ ├── nopt@1.0.10 
│ ├── proto-list@1.0.0 
│ ├── read@0.0.2 
│ ├── request@2.9.153 
│ ├── rimraf@2.0.1 
│ ├── semver@1.0.13 
│ ├── slide@1.1.3 
│ ├── tar@0.1.13 
│ ├── uid-number@0.0.3 
│ └── which@1.0.5 
└─┬ socket.io@0.9.6 
  ├── policyfile@0.0.4 
  ├── redis@0.6.7 
  └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.6 
    ├─┬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1 
    │ └── zeparser@0.0.5 
    ├── uglify-js@1.2.5 
    ├─┬ ws@0.4.14 
    │ ├── commander@0.5.2 
    │ └── options@0.0.3 
    └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2
```

I add that it is the only module who generate this error.

Also, I don't really understand the way are encapsulated some module, it appears that npm is installing the module directly in the directory I'm using the module installation command, and I notice that formidable has been installed in the express/connect/ module on its first installation.

Can you give me more information about the module installation tree.
Thank for your replies

Cheers

Comment: Don't panic! Stay calm, think where did you lastly see the _formidable Node.js_... :)

Comment: Can we please see the code where you try to require formidable? Otherwise how can we do anything at all to help you...

Comment: I'm calling the require of the modules directly at the beginning of my file.js, I'm using this call : var formidable = require("formidable");

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from the NODE_PATH environment var. If I call the complete path unto the node modules, then it works. where am i supposed to set this var, because it sounds like my bash_profile doesn't work for NODE_PATH.

Comment: My mistake, it's about my env PATH.
Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I'm having *exactly* this problem - can't find formidable - but none of the suggestions here resolved it. I'm very puzzled. I can (manually) find the formidable folder but it does not contain a file formidable.js, rather it's a whole tree of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand module resolution, have a look at the [Modules documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), especially [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

> For example, if the file at `'/home/ry/projects/foo.js'` called `require('bar.js')`, then node would look in the following locations, in this order:
>
> - `/home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/ry/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/node_modules/bar.js`

NPM takes advantage of this by installing modules into:

```
./node_modules/{module}
```

So, when you use `npm install formidable`, it will create and install the module into:

```
./node_modules/formidable
```

But, this means that only scripts within the current directory, including sub-directories, will succeed in using `require('formidable')`:

```
./foo.js
./lib/bar.js
./src/baz.js
./src/sub/qux.js
```

You can however install modules as "global," but you have to explicitly ask for it with `-g` or `--global`:

```
npm install -g formidable
```

Then, any script on the system should be able to `require('formidable')`.

---

As for the tree output, you current have 5 installed modules available from the current directory:

- `express`
- `formidable`
- `node-inspector`
- `npm`
- `socket.io`

Everything else in the tree is a list of these modules' dependencies, and their dependencies, etc., but only these 5 are available for `require(...)` within your scripts.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer looks very comprehensive and correct, but this worked for me:

```
npm install -d
```

d stands for dependencies (I think)

Comment: +1 it helped me _C:\Users\yash\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\selenium-webdriver\2.47.0\package\example_   `ctrl + shift + open command window here` then used `npm install -d` it installed all dependencies then run an example `node google_search.js`

Comment: Thanks for that! Suddenly, it's added to the project dependencies  . . .