# can not find module formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot find module formidable - Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467668/cannot-find-module-formidable-node-js)

I an trying to develop a node.js project.
But when i try to execute it shows the 
**ERROR  - can not find module 'formidable'**
I have already tried 
**npm install -g formidable**
 and 
**npm install -d**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As a sidenote, it would be really helpful to see why that question had much better chance of actually been answered.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Install using npm install formidable without the -g option. The -g option installs it globally and cannot be accessed locally. http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/ is a useful read.

Comment: **npm install formidable**
solved the problem.
Thank you everyone.